# How can I delete a certain element from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about deleting one of these students from a list of tuples? I'm quite confused on this part and not sure where to start. Could anyone help point me in the correct direction?

```
select=True
data=[]
while select:
    print (""" 
    student  Database   (student records:)
    a. Delete a student from the database
    """ )
    select=input("What would you like to do? ")
    if select == "1":
    print("Add a new student") 
    student = input ("Enter studenbt:")
    grades = input ("Enter grade:")
    entermark = float (input ("enter mark:"))

    fulltime = input ("Is the student full-time? Yes/No:")


    data.append((student, grades, entermark, )) 
    print ("The student you have entered is:",data)

elif select == "a":
    delete = input("student do delete?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`dict`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) from your data instead of `list`. Then you can simply delete the item you want with `data.pop(key)` in a constant time.

```
data = {}

# this is how you add data
data['studentName1'] = (10,20)
data['studentName2'] = (32,42)

# this is how you remove data
data.pop('studentName1')
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think that @sudomakeinstall2's suggestion of using a dictionary to store your data instead of a list is a good one.  If you simply must use a list, then my answer below should help with that.

You can remove an element of a list if you know its index by using the `pop()` method.

For example:

```
>>> data.pop(5)
```

Will remove the 5th element.

In your case, you will want to find the index for the student you want to remove, then use `pop()` to remove it.

For example you could find the student by iterating through your list like this:

```
delete = input("Which employee would you like to delete from the database?")
for index, row in enumerate(data):
    if row[0] == delete:
        data.pop(index)
        break
```

Comment: im quite new to python and so I can do some basic stuff but I don't understand stuff like enumerate so I don't want to use it without knowing what it is otherwise I feel like I won't learn.. I know it might be a problem, but if u find some spare time could u mind explaining everything after the input ? Thanks.

Comment: this is a good answer for this example but its worth noting that this may not work for deleting multiple items especially when the items are consecutive